# Call functions from another file with two different controllers on AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a web page, and i need to call some funtions that lives on another file.

This is `header.js`:

```
(function(){

var head = {
    templateUrl: '/app/components/include/header.html',
    controller: headCtrl
};

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .component('adminHead', head);
    headCtrl.$inject = ["$http"];
    function headCtrl($http){

        function test() {
            console.log('How ya doin?');
            }                  

     }

})();
```

What i wanna do is to call the function `test()` on the `home.js` file:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var home = {
        templateUrl: '/app/components/home/admin-home.html',
        controller: adminHomeCtrl
    };

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .component('adminHome', home);
        adminHomeCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$cookies"];
        function adminHomeCtrl($scope, $http, $cookies){


        }
})();
```

As you can see, there are two different controllers, so, what will be the best way to call the function? Someone can help me with an example, please? I'm very lost...

I'm working with AngularJs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you user angular services for - to provide common functionality between different controllers. Something like:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('adminApp')
    .factory('MyService', ['myDependency', function (myDependency) {
      const s = {
        test: function() {
          // test stuff
        },
      };
      return s;
    }]);
})();
```

Then inject MyService into each controller as a dependency and call `MyService.test()` as required.

Comment: Thanks!. I've created a file call `excelsior.js` and put the piece of code you write. Then adden into my `index.html`, and as a last step, injected into the controller like this: `adminHomeCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$cookies", "MyService"]; function adminHomeCtrl($scope, $http, $cookies, MyService)...`, but now, i'm getting the error: `$injector:unpr`